# PHP How to Handle SOAP Responce

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need to check the result of an if statement

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/message.asmx?wsdl");
/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
    "recepient" => "$recipient",
    "short_message" => "$text",
    "message_id" => $smsid,
    "deadline" => $deadline,
    "user_id" => "$userid"
);

/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
$response = $client->__soapCall("Standard", array($params));

var_dump($response);
```

I get responce

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["StandardResult"]=> bool(true) }
```

How can I write an if statement to check if StandardResult has value of true.
Also if I get StandardResult as 'SENT' how could I use/get that?
I basically want to:

```
if ($responce['StandardResult'] == true) {
    echo "Expectancy is met";
}
```

or

```
if ($responce['StandardResult'] == 'SENT') {
    echo "Expectancy is met";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a object, so you can access like property access.

```
if ($response->StandardResult) {
}
```

Comment: What if StandardResult is no longer bool(true), but text. Can I....
    if ($response->StandardResult == 'SENT') {}

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Why you not check this?